# PostgreSQL: How to copy data from one database table to another database

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I need simple example how to copy data from database **DB1** table **T1** to database **DB2** table **T2**.

**T2** has identical structure like **T1** (same column names, properties. Just different data)
DB2 running on same server like DB1, but on different port.

Comment: Use a foreign data wrapper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the case the two databases are on two different server instances, you could export in CSV from `db1` and then import the data in `db2` :

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM t1) TO '/home/export.csv';
```

and then load back into `db2` :

```
COPY t2 FROM '/home/export.csv';
```

*Again, the two tables on the two different database instances must have the same structure.*

Using the command line tools : pg_dump and psql , you could do even in this way :

```
pg_dump -U postgres -t t1 db1 | psql -U postgres -d db2
```

You can specify command line arguments to both `pg_dump` and `psql` to specify the address and/or port of the server .

Another option would be to use an external tool like : [openDBcopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net), to perform the migration/copy of the table.

Comment: The first statement is not supported in Postgres you can't reference tables in a different database like that. (and besides `db2.t2` references a table in the _schema_ `db2`, not the "database" db2)

Comment: The first statement will **not** work across databases (only across _schema_ which is what your statement is doing)

Comment: Removed, since the actual solution for the question, is to export in CSV and import back.

Comment: Why `COPY (SELECT * FROM t1)` and not `COPY t1`? Also, omit the `db1` and `db2` qualifiers.

Comment: Okey. csv solution is accepted. But 1 problem remains. When copying into db2 i need sames values except ID. I need insert like new rows with new ID's. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can import the CSV into a temporary table, and then insert into the actual table only the columns that you need. Take a look here for more information : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql

Comment: A second method of using COPY (with the benefit that it would work even if the two dbs were on different servers): `psql db1 -c 'COPY (SELECT * FROM t1) TO stdout' | psql db2 -c 'COPY t2 FROM stdin'`

Answer (score 6):

You can try this one -

```
 pg_dump -t table_name_to_copy source_db | psql target_db
```

Comment: upvoted! how do you copy only 4 columns from table1 of database 1 to 4 columns of table1 of database2?